# How to set the value of a hidden field in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to set the value of a hidden field in javascript?

```js
document.getElementById("pid").value = 1234;
alert(document.getElementById("pid").value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="pid" value="@Model.pid" />
```

**the alert shows undefined**

what I missed?

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/b2qynstp/)

Comment: I cannot reproduce, can you please add a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1048572) to your answer that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: "_what I missed?_" Nothing - your code works fine.

Comment: Your code is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine check this out.

```js
document.getElementById("pid").value = 1234;
alert(document.getElementById("pid").value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="pid" value="@Model.pid" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code snippet works fine as it should but as an extension to it you can use a function called `setAttribute`

```js
document.getElementById("pid").setAttribute("value", 1234);
alert(document.getElementById("pid").value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="pid" value="@Model.pid" />
```

although your code works you can still using this function `setAttribute` you can setAttribute of any HTML Element

Read More About it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)